# do something when a class got added

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following scenario:

I need to call a function, when a library i use, is adding a class to a DOM element. I am using angularjs. I have no clue how i can do it, so i hope you can help me.

```
<div class="block active"></div>
```

Well this is my div and everytime the active class gets added or removed i want need to call a js function to make some changed on the side.

```
ControllersModule.controller('BlockCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$location',
    function ($scope, $location) {

    }
]);
```

I hope you can help me, This is the Controller what should handle this.

Comment: does your library throw an event when manipulating your div? in principle, you can bind to those events in angular.

Comment: well i am using bootstrap. and when i click on a.dropdown-toggle then the parent list item (li) gehts the class open

Comment: If you're using twitter bootstrap and angular you can use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.

Comment: well but that doesn't solve my problem. because I need to make things visible that are outside of the dropdown item. Therefore I need to trigger that change

Comment: Modern browsers have DOM Mutation observers that could help you in observing when `class` `attribute` for your `DOM element` has changed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Example_usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar in my project here (https://bitbucket.org/asiemer/angularjs.mvc/wiki/Home) in which I created a "validated" directive inside of which a watcher is defined.  In the watcher I check the class names that are defined.

Something like this:

```
scope.$watch(modelId, function (newValue, oldValue, $scope) {
        var classes = element[0].className;
        if (classes.indexOf(' ng-invalid ') > 0 && classes.indexOf('ng-pristine') == -1) {
            angular.element('#'+validationMessageId).css('display', 'inline');
        }
        else
        {
            angular.element('#'+validationMessageId).css('display', 'none');
        }
        scope.$apply();
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a paradox.

If you want the css class to be changed by some non-angularjs logic, angularjs will not detect the change since it is made *outside* scope.

If you want angularjs to change the css class, you will be able to know when the css class is changed since the change must be made *inside* the angularjs's scope.